# how to create the new directory in xampp

Tags: 14.04, xampp

I have installed the xampp on Ubuntu 14.4. i don't know where to
create the new directory i mean which path ?

I'm new user to Ubuntu please suggest me ideas ?

I gone to `opt/lamp/ht docs/` i didn't able to create the new folder
? The options are disabled ? how can i solve this ?

How to copy my existing projects and paste my `htdocs` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for creating the folder inside `/` you need root permisions

for creating the folder inside `opt/lamp/ht docs/`

open the terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
and change the directory to it by typing

```
cd /opt/lamp/ht\ docs/
```

and make directory using the command

```
sudo mkdir <dir name>
```

and to copy the files to docs first change the directory where your files are located using the following command

```
cd <directory containing the docs>
```

and type the following commands

```
sudo cp <docs> /opt/lamp/ht\ docs/
```

Comment: wanna create via terminal ?

Comment: how to copy and paste my project folder in htdocs ?